# Jackson QName serailization without namesampe/prefix

Tags: java, xml, json, serialization, jackson

I'm trying to serialze a Map using Jackson 2, the default ObjectMapper() gives something like:

{"{http://google.com/}myName":"myValue"}

It probably uses QName.toString() method to serialize the qname key.

I tried following to register a custom serializer for QName, but it is not getting invoked.

```
public static class QnameSerializer extends JsonSerializer<QName> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(QName value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
        jgen.writeString(value.getLocalPart());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addKeySerializer(QName.class, new QnameSerializer());
    // tried module.addSerializer(QName.class, new QnameSerializer()) also
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(module);
    Map<QName, String> m =ImmutableMap.of(new QName("http://google.com/","myName","pre"), "myValue");
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(m));
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you please show us the Map or serialized string that you are deserializing.

Comment: @ankur-singhal that was a typo, I've the map and I'm serializing it.
Map: ImmutableMap.of(new QName("http://google.com/","myName","pre"), "myValue")
Serailized string: {"{http://google.com/}myName":"myValue"}

Comment: Just want to get the exact peiece of code, the data your are putting inside the map to serialize and deserialize

Comment: Following is the map I'm creating:
Map<QName, String> m =ImmutableMap.of(new QName("http://google.com/","myName","pre"), "myValue");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson needs to know the generic map type at runtime to find out that the keys should be serialized by the custom serializer. You should use [the type reference](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Data_Binding_with_Generics) when creating a writer as follows:

```
public class JacksonQName {
    public static class QnameSerializer extends JsonSerializer<QName> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(QName value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
                throws IOException {
            System.out.println("QName serializer works");
            jgen.writeFieldName(value.getLocalPart());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addKeySerializer(QName.class, new QnameSerializer());
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        Map<QName, String> m = ImmutableMap.of(
                new QName("http://google.com/", "myName", "pre"),
                "myValue");
        TypeReference<Map<QName, String>> type = new TypeReference<Map<QName, String>>() {};
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithType(type).writeValueAsString(m));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
QName serializer works
{"myName":"myValue"}
```